# How to set Java enum field from JNI?

Tags: java, enums, java-native-interface

How do I **set** Java enum field from JNI ? Here is the sample code. I would like to set "myState" field of my B object in the native function "get_state".

```
public class A {

    public enum STATE { 
        STATE_ONE,
        STATE_TWO
    }

    public static class B {
        public STATE myState;
    }

    public native void get_state(B b);

    public B getB() {
        B b;

        // Call JNI to get the state
        get_state(b);

        return b;
    }
}


JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_A_get_1state(JNIEnv *env, jobject object, jobject b_object)
{
    /* Get a reference to obj's class */
    jclass cls = (*env)->GetObjectClass(env, b_object);

    //How do I set B object's "myState" field?

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to return enum from JNI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11225261/how-to-return-enum-from-jni)

Comment: Don't think "how to return enum from JNI" is a duplicate, OP is looking to set a value. I have the same question, will post an answer here if I can find it.

Answer (score 6):

Since it is a nested enum class, STATE is implicitly static. There are numerous resources, but a Google search that says exactly this can be found here: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=1

This allows for another approach on top of valueOF methodID from enum class. You can use env->GetStaticField and env->GetStaticObjectField to get the enum to set.

Ex:

```
jclass theStateClass = env->FindClass("your/containingPackage/A$STATE");
jfieldID stateOneField    = env->GetStaticFieldID(theStateClass, "STATE_ONE", "Lyour/containingPackage/A$STATE;");
jobject STATE_ONE = env->GetStaticObjectField(theStateClass, stateOneField);
```

Comment: This is brilliant but the example given is incorrect. I'll attempt to edit it but essentially STATE_ONE and STATE_TWO are static final members of class STATE so GetStaticObjectField and ..FieldID need a class reference to STATE not A

Comment: All the responses here slightly miss the point of the original question. That is, is it possible to update an instance (non-static declared) Enum type field, a field declared in the same Java class as a native method/JNI function, directly from within the JNI function (without updating the class field using an assignment from the JNI function's return type, returning an jobject). If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Just like you would do it from Java when you only have the name of the enum:

1. Look up the class instance via JNI.
2. Invoke the `valueOf(String)` method on the enum class

Comment: I would like to set the said enum field, similarly if the said field was of type String    `char* str = strdup("Hello");
  
  jfieldID fid = (*env)->GetFieldID(env, cls, "myState", "Ljava/lang/String;");
  jstring jstr = (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, str);
  (*env)->SetObjectField(env, b_object, fid, jstr);
  
  free(str);
  (*env)->DeleteLocalRef(env, jpin);`
  
  So how can i invoke SetObjectField or similar method on java enum type field on my b_object?

Comment: As I said: Invoke `STATE.valueOf("STATE_ONE")` from JNI to get the instance and then use `SetObjectField` with the value to change the field.

Answer (score 0):

Inolder to build this class,I had done some minor modification.

```
public class A {

    public enum STATE { 
        STATE_ONE,
        STATE_TWO
    }

    

    public native void get_state(B b);

    public B getB() {
        B b = new B();

        // Call JNI to get the state
        get_state(b);

        return b;
    }
    
    public static class B {
        public STATE myState = STATE.STATE_ONE;
        
    }
}
```

so here we go.
the first step is to build the java class

```
javac A.java
```

so We got an A.class file.

second,generate the signature.

```
javap -v A
```

the shell prints the following:

```
C:\Users\bowman\Desktop\project>javap -v -p -c A
Classfile /C:/Users/bowman/Desktop/project/A.class
  Last modified 2014-1-3; size 377 bytes
  MD5 checksum f331eddf740b0d8c256c851f04369088
  Compiled from "A.java"
public class A
  SourceFile: "A.java"
  InnerClasses:
       public static #7= #2 of #5; //B=class A$B of class A
       public static final #10= #9 of #5; //STATE=class A$STATE of class A
  minor version: 0
  major version: 51
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER
Constant pool:
   #1 = Methodref          #6.#21         //  java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
   #2 = Class              #22            //  A$B
   #3 = Methodref          #2.#21         //  A$B."<init>":()V
   #4 = Methodref          #5.#23         //  A.get_state:(LA$B;)V
   #5 = Class              #24            //  A
   #6 = Class              #25            //  java/lang/Object
   #7 = Utf8               B
   #8 = Utf8               InnerClasses
   #9 = Class              #26            //  A$STATE
  #10 = Utf8               STATE
  #11 = Utf8               <init>
etc...
```

the main point is :

> public class A
>
> SourceFile: "A.java"
>
> InnerClasses:
>
> public static #7= #2 of #5; //B=class A$B of class A
>
> public static final #10= #9 of #5; //STATE=class A$STATE of class A

so We can make a consulation that the enum is a class which has a signature of "A$STATE"

you can get this class in cpp by:

```
jclass A_State = env->FindClass( "LA$STATE;");
```

hope it helps.