# Comparing JNI object references

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

I call a Java method from c++ via JNI. The Java method returns an enum STATUS. I already have the jobjects representing the enums in my c++ code like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17441151/3352197

```
jclass clSTATUS    = env->FindClass("MyClass$STATUS");
jfieldID fidONE    = env->GetStaticFieldID(clSTATUS , "ONE", "LMyClass$STATUS;");
jobject STATUS_ONE = env->GetStaticObjectField(clSTATUS, fidONE);
```

So, the call

```
jobject o = env->CallObjectMethod(jTestobject, test);
```

returns a jobject representing an enum STATUS, specially ONE. So, how do I know which enum it has returned?
I tried to compare it to `STATUS_ONE`, but they do not match.

Comment: how did you compare `o` with `STATUS_ONE`?

Comment: just with ==, but this might be false?
I also printed both, but they have different pointers (or so).

Comment: try using the `equals` method.  Not sure if `env->IsSameObject(o,STATUS_ONE)` calls that or not

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Found it by myself, after Samhain pointed out my possible mistake.
You just have to compare the objects correctly:

```
env->IsSameObject(o, STATUS_ONE);
```

Thank you!